Upgraded to 24.04LTS from 22.04 and network doesn't work at all
I can't connect to the internet neither using wired connection nor USB modem (desktop PC, no wifi). Checked status of NetworkManager - it works. But internet still unavailable. Tried different approaches - interface adding, netplan using and other - didn't help.
What should I do?



To start with exact details of what you have tried and the results need to be added to the question with the edit option.

@DavidDE can I add images from my cell phone? I'm not able to make screenshot because I don't have any connection on my PC

The first 2 pics are worthless and the last 2 have most of the data cut off.  They are also so large they took nearly a minute to download and display and I have a fast connection. So no sorry the pics do not help at all. I asked for what you have tried I do not see that info here. Sorry with the info you have supplied there is nothing that can be used to help you.

After some research I found out that the file /etc/resolv.conf  either damaged or not existed. At least I couldn't open it. So in my case I first removed the file in case if it existed but damaged using command:
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

And then checked status by command:
systemctl status systemd-resolved.service

The status was active(runnig). After that I checked if I have a stub-resolv.conf file by command:
cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

and got its content which says

This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf

and other things.
So I tried the command:
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

which actually creates a symlink.
After all these steps I got everything work as expected.

I have the same problem and I found this answer worked for me
Bug connection ubuntu
Summary, my steps are

Run


sudo apt install systemd-resolved


disconnect wifi/ wired

turn on wifi again

connect successfully



Thanks, but this didn't help

Erase the old Connections in Networkmanager  and create anew.
